# XSL attribute value not getting displayed

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Here is my xml:

```
<RESPONSE heading="Broker List">
     <RESULTSET nbr="1" rowcount="11">
         <ROW nbr="1">
             <COL nbr="1" name="broker_name" datatype="String" href="api">BARC</COL>
             <COL nbr="2" name="broker_id" datatype="String">11</COL>
         </ROW>
     </RESULTSET>
</RESPONSE>
```

This xls works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/RESPONSE">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body class='data'>
  <h2><xsl:value-of select="./@heading"/></h2>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="RESULTSET" />
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="RESULTSET">
     <table id="result" class="sortable-theme-finder" data-sortable="">
        <thead>
         <xsl:for-each select="ROW[1]/COL">
             <th> <xsl:value-of select="@name" /></th>
         </xsl:for-each>
        </thead>  
        <tbody>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="ROW" />
        </tbody>  
    </table>
    <br/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ROW" >
      <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="COL" />
     </tr>  
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="COL">
       <td border="1">
           <a><xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="@href"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </a>  
       </td>
   </xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

resulting in this:

```
<tr>
    <td border="1"><a href="broker_name">BARC</a></td>
    <td border="1"><a href="broker_id">11 </a></td>
 </tr>
```

however if I change this line:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@name" />
```

to

```
<xsl:value-of select="@href" />
```

the result is this:

```
<tr>
    <td border="1"><a href="">BARC</a></td>
    <td border="1"><a href="">11 </a></td>
 </tr>
```

Why does the @href attribute not get selected? It will only accept the name attribute. Tried 'id' too but no go. I am using C# XslCompiledTransform to perform the transformation.  Thanks!

Comment: There's no `href` attribute in the source XML. The only similar one is `ref`.

Comment: i updated the xml to show href now (which still does not work). I thought perhaps href was a reserved word so i tried ref and other attributes names.

Comment: Sorry, I had to step out for a few hours.  I have put in full xsl as you requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing

```
<xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></xsl:attribute>
```

to

```
<xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="@href"/></xsl:attribute>
```

*does* work in this context (the current context nodes inside `xsl:for-each`). I have slightly adapted your stylesheet to the following, but it works in similar ways:

**XSLT Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="ROW" >
      <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </tr>  
   </xsl:template>
   
   <xsl:template match="COL">
       <td border="1">
           <a>
               <xsl:copy-of select="@href"/>
               <xsl:apply-templates/>
           </a>
       </td>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

**XML Output**

And the output will be, given exactly the input document you show:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tr>
   <td border="1">
      <a href="api">BARC</a>
   </td>
   <td border="1">
      <a>11</a>
   </td>
</tr>
```

As you can see, the `href` attribute is kept - for the single `COL` element where it occurred in the input.

Try this solution [online here](http://xsltransform.net/gWmuiKo).

---

> I thought perhaps href was a reserved word so i tried ref and other attributes names.

No, "href" is not a reserved name in XML and has no predefined semantics, as it does in HTML.

```
<xsl:value-of select="@href"/>
```

will only ever retrieve content from the attribute that is called "href".

Comment: Thanks. I tried the fiddle you put together and that does indeed work, however when I apply this to my code, I'm still failing. Also, the above xml has a tag called datatype.  When I use that tag, it then works.  Ah, i just realized that perhaps it is failing because only one of the COL nodes has the href attr?

Comment: @user3102739 What do you mean exactly by "applying it to your code"? If there are other templates in your stylesheet, please edit your question to show _all_ the code that is relevant to the question. And no, if only one `COL` element has an `href` attribute in the input, then only _one_ `href` should be empty in the result, but not the other. This applies to both your initial and my version of the code.

Comment: As you can see from my xsl, I don't perform a transform with it, but do that with C#, where as your sample used transform statements.